# regarding calculating business days/holidays

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

does anyone know where I can download this zip file called "businessdays.zip" which was mentioned from this link ... http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=136159 ... I mean is there a better way of calculating business days/holidays than what is previously written here ... http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Reporting_/Crystal_Reports/Q_21376129.html ... I've tried this but method from experts-exchange, registered the dll but still not working for me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a custom function that returns an array of holidays.  See my answer to [Crystal Report exclude time entries based on holiday rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043752/crystal-report-exclude-time-entries-based-on-holiday-rules).

Answer (score 0):

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646487/909134) there is a function that takes a start date, and end date and return the number of working days in between. Also takes holidays into account.