# Crystal Reports 2011 calculate number of days worked in a given date range

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to come up with a utilization report for artisans. The report prompts for a start date and an end date. It should then check in the Leave table if an artisan was on leave on any of the days in the date range and add the leave days to weekends and public holidays in the specified date range and then subtract the total count of the above from the number of days in the date range (this is done to remain with only a count of the days when the artisan was actually at work). How best can I achieve this using Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

A formula for counting workdays between two dates can be found [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14646487/909134).

You could get the number of leave dates from a running total in a subreport and return that as a shared variable to the main report (if not possible to have that in the main report which would be easier if no other data is to be obtained). Then substract that number from the result of the formula linked to above.
Use parameters on the subreport and link the main report date parameters to them.